# Is it possible to slide a row of images in a windows form Panel?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Out of curiosity, if I have a panel as part of a windows form application that has dozens of images in rows can those images be shifted left or right along the row using a button? If so could someone post an example of how to do so?

I've seen a lot of posts about moving rows/lines up and down or switching data but nothing about sliding a row horizontally one place at a time.

I'll add a picture to try and give an idea of what I am asking.

[image: Panel with Images]

Comment: Check out WPF. It is a learning curve but they have animation.

Comment: I will look into that thank you. All of this is a learning curve for me. Have only been teaching myself programming for 3 months now.

Comment: Presumably these are PictureBox controls, hard to tell.  Simply calling its SetChildIndex() method is enough to move it.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see a .SetChildIndex method for a PictureBox in WinForms.

Comment: Simply google "windows forms setchildindex" to find out how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

What I'd recommend doing is using a FlowLayoutPanel and simply setting the the PictureBoxes' index based on if you want to shift them to the left or to the right. To illustrate what I mean, if you wanted to move your images to the left you would use:

```
With FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    .SetChildIndex(.Item(0), .Count - 1)
End With
```

Then if you wanted to move your images to the right you would use:

```
With FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    .SetChildIndex(.Item(.Count - 1), 0)
End With
```

This allows the FlowLayoutPanel to handle where the control is to be positioned.